# Where can I get replacement parts for Canon cameras?

Tags: canon, repair, diy

My son accidentally cracked a glass on the back of the camera. It is not an LCD itself, but rather a protective cover over the LCD. I took the camera to photo store and they said they can order the part and fix it but for nearly $130, most of which is labor. Where can I order the part? I'm pretty certain I can handle the replacement myself?

Comment: A google search for the camera model and "replacement screen" will net you many companies that supply such parts.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I called Canon and they won't sell the part but want for me to mail in the camera for repair at the factory. They could not give me the exact estimate as the model is too new but the older cameras were fixed between $69 - $140. I checked ebay and found entire pack cover for $16. I can swap it myself.

Comment: Bear in mind doing the work yourself will void the warranty on the camera, and also you should find a good 'guide' to doing it.  Many of these glass coverings these days are glued into place and can be difficult or near on impossible to remove unless you know what you are doing.  The $130 may be worth it, not necessarily for the physical cost of the part and labour, but for the peace of mind and warranty too :-)

Comment: Search Amazon.com! I get all my replacement stuff there...

Answer (score 2):

In the US, [USCamera.com](http://www.uscamera.com/) is a reputable supplier of a limited number of camera parts.  I've purchased flash replacement parts from them without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Ebay is usually a pretty good place to get replacement parts for old cameras, but Amazon has very nice packs with different replacement parts for new cameras. Keep in mind, though that if you decide to use Ebay, most of the stuff there is used. This effectively reduces the price, but the quality could suffer as well. Whenever I buy products from Ebay, I never buy a product unless I can see pictures and it provides an adequate description.

Answer (score 1):

I had an LCD crack on a Canon S60, that I had bought second-hand for about $80. I lurked a while, but was able to buy a S70 on eBay which had a non-working lens and a original case for $25. I was going to change the screen out, but I ended up just swapping the camera back, precisely so I didn't have to pry the replacement screen from the glue. This might be a good option for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try ifixit - they offer parts and online repair guides

http://www.ifixit.com/Device/Canon_Camera